# Boost graph library using two visitors

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

After some tests I observer that the stamp_times visitor is the problem:

```
typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS> Graph;
typedef graph_traits <Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
typedef graph_traits <Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;


Graph g(edges.begin(), edges.end(), n);

typedef graph_traits <Graph>::vertices_size_type Size;

std::vector<Size> dtime(num_vertices(g));
Size time = 0;

breadth_first_search(g, s, visitor(make_bfs_visitor(
                       stamp_times(dtime.begin(), time, on_discover_vertex()))));
```

(I got more less the same error with that code).

I need to use two visitors one to record predecessors and a second one two obtain visiting time.

```
boost::breadth_first_search
    (g, s,
     boost::visitor(boost::make_bfs_visitor
            (std::make_pair(
            boost::record_predecessors(&p[0], boost::on_tree_edge()),
            stamp_times(dtime.begin(), time, on_discover_vertex())))));
```

But this code event do not compile. I get following error.

```
/usr/include/boost/graph/visitors.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::time_stamper<TimeMap, TimeT, Tag>::operator()(Vertex, const Graph&) [with Vertex = long unsigned int, Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>, TimeMap = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, TimeT = long unsigned int, Tag = boost::on_discover_vertex]’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/visitors.hpp:109:8:   instantiated from ‘void boost::detail::invoke_dispatch(Visitor&, T, Graph&, mpl_::true_) [with Visitor = boost::time_stamper<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, long unsigned int, boost::on_discover_vertex>, T = long unsigned int, Graph = const boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>, mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/visitors.hpp:140:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::invoke_visitors(Visitor&, T, Graph&, Tag) [with Visitor = boost::time_stamper<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, long unsigned int, boost::on_discover_vertex>, T = long unsigned int, Graph = const boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>, Tag = boost::on_discover_vertex]’
```

Comment: The error was: `error: no matching function for call to 'put(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long unsigned int*, std::vector<long long unsigned int> >&, long long unsigned int&, long long unsigned int&)'`. Changing `dtime.begin()` with `&dtime[0]` solves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`stamp_times`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/time_stamper.html) (and the other EventVisitors) expects a [`WritablePropertyMap`](http://www.boost.org/libs/property_map/doc/WritablePropertyMap.html). According to [this](http://www.boost.org/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html#sec%3aproperty-map-types) there are specializations of `property_traits` that allow using c++ pointers as property maps and according to [this](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html) "Since the iterator of a std::vector (obtained with a call to begin()) is a pointer, the pointer property map method also works for std::vector::iterator". Apparently this last part is not true with recent versions of g++ (tested on 4.6.3 and 4.7.1). So in order to invoke `stamp_times` you need to use `&dtime[0]` instead of `dtime.begin()`.

Comment: ok. I are right. Thanks a lot but. I assumed wrongly that if sth is written in manual, it is correct.

Comment: I wish I had more than one upvote for this answer, it solved a lot of my BGL problems and confusions.